# Appending ruby partial w('<%= characters) to end of file with SED

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I am trying to add this line to the end a set of files:

```
<%= render 'success_guide_menu' %>
```

All of these files begin with 'school_guide'.

I tried to use the following sed script:

```
sed "
$ a\
<%= render 'school_guide_menu' %>
" school_guide*
```

but I get an error that says

```
 sed: 1: "$ a\<\%\= render 'schoo ...": extra characters after \ at the end of a command
```

I have tried to escape the characters with no success and am not really sure what sed is referring to in this error because it dosen't seem to be the files and (I think) it is also reading in the entire string. Help?

Comment: hey, do you really want to cat all files and append a line as you do now or you want to append to each of them?

Comment: make sure that the '\' is the last char on the line. Having a space or tab after the '\' will give this error message. You may also need a blank line before the closing `"` char. Also, the shell maybe processing the `$` char, so as a last resort try `\$`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not a bash one-line script?

```
for file in $(ls school_guide*); do echo "<%= render 'success_guide_menu' %>" >> $file; done
```

Comment: Avoid to loop throught files using `ls`. It will break files with newlines. Use `for file in school_guide*; do ...` instead. And double quote `$file` at the end of the command, otherwise could be broken if it contains spaces, change it to `... >> "$file"`

Comment: thank you, this worked. this is actually the first time i use the shell for that (or even try to use sed). still a little frustrated as to why i couldn't get it to work via sed when it seems like it would be a good application of the tool...might try to use it another time

Answer (score 0):

One way using `sed`. I use `-i` switch with a `.bak` suffix to modify files in-place and create backups.

```
sed -i.bak -e "$ a\<%= render 'success_guide_menu' %>" school_guide*
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '$a\<%= render '\''school_guide_menu'\'' %>' school_guide*
```